# How to re assign a variable in Erlang?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm new to Erlang and this is a question I didn't get a proper answer surfing through the internet for several days.
I want to code something as shown in following code segment (consider it as pseudo code) :

```
Check =false;
lists:foreach(fun(Row) -> 
      if somecondition -> 
          Check = true;
        true -> ok 
      end
end, RowList)
```

At the end I need to get the value of variable Check. As in Erlang we can't re-"assign" a value to a variable, how can I get the value of Check at the end of the code block shown above ?

Comment: Quick note: you likely won't be using lists:foreach very much in Erlang, certainly not as much as similar constructs in non-functional languages.  lists:foreach is mainly useful if you need to do something purely for the side effect, e.g. printing out each value in the list.  Instead of reaching for lists:foreach when you want to iterate over a list, think about transforming/inspecting through higher-level functions like lists:foldl, lists:map, lists:any, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use this `lists:any/2`.
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#any-2

```
lists:any(fun(Row) -> somecondition end, RowList).
```

Comment: I'm sure you can use that ;)

Comment: It does the job! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The generic way to go through a list and modify a value for each element is to use `lists:foldl/3` http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3. For your specific example it is easier and shorter to use lists:any/2 as above.